# sales mailing without store logo doesnt show

Tags: email, transactional-mail, logo

the store logo does not appear in the transactional emails, and if the image exists but it does not show it

[image]

Comment: Can you please check if right click on image and select open image in new tap , does that image shows or you get an error

Comment: when I click on the image, it redirects me to a page that does not exist, giving a 404 error :(

Comment: Then it's a permission issue at your server end